# RFC_READ_TABLE concatenates columns in row results

Tags: saprfc

The following query concatenates the columns results for each row.  I need to separate columns with either some kind of delimiter or unique `row[i]` results.

Query: `"exec rfc_read_table @query_table='VBAK', @rowcount=50, @FIELDS= '<FIELDS><RFC_DB_FLD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/"><FIELDNAME>MANDT</FIELDNAME></RFC_DB_FLD><RFC_DB_FLD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/"><FIELDNAME>VBELN</FIELDNAME></RFC_DB_FLD></FIELDS>,@fields=@flds output'"`

.NET

```
          using (SAPCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {                        
                cmd.CommandText = //See query above

                
                SAPDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0} ", rdr[0]);
                    //Console.Write(" {0} ", rdr[1]);//null...
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
```

**UPDATE**
I am able to separate the columns by following the indexes returned by

```
DataTable dtFields = (DataTable)cmd.Parameters["@flds"].Value;
```

(updated query)

The process is so clunky and tosses up exceptions because the indexes become unreliable when the last columns in the query return empty results (also found a length indicator that was wrong).  I worked around most of it, but this is so bad.  Is there a better supported method to query SAP with .NET?

Answer (score 1):

it works for me.

ADD this --> in your script:

```
   @DELIMITER ='|'
```

`"exec rfc_read_table @query_table='VBAK', @rowcount=50, @DELIMITER ='|', @FIELDS= '<FIELDS><RFC_DB_FLD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/"><FIELDNAME>MANDT</FIELDNAME></RFC_DB_FLD><RFC_DB_FLD xmlns="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Rfc/"><FIELDNAME>VBELN</FIELDNAME></RFC_DB_FLD></FIELDS>,@fields=@flds output'"`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but in Version 3 of SAP .NET connector such problem should be resolved.

Comment: I believe thats the version we downloaded.